# React Testing Library | React Router 6 "navigate" does not update history

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

I am currently struggling with react router 6 and its useNavigate Hook.
Basically I am testing a small component consisting of a login mask. After entering all data, the user should be redirected to the root page (from "/login" to "/"). Although it does work on my local page, the test refuses to work.

My Component:

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import LoginButton from "../login-button/LoginButton";
import LoginInput from "../login-input";
import PD2Logo from "assets/images/pd2_logo.png";

import { LoginFormContainer, ErrorMessage, Title, Logo } from "./styles";

const LoginForm = () => {
  const [login, setLogin] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleLogin = useCallback(
    async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      setError(null);
      try {
        await axios.post("/api/user/login", {
          login,
          password,
        });
        // The test DOES reach that line
        navigate("/");
      } catch (response) {
        setError(response.data);
      }
    },
    [login, password]
  );

  return (
    <LoginFormContainer onSubmit={handleLogin}>
      <Logo alt="p2d-logo" src={PD2Logo} />
      <Title>Login</Title>
      <LoginInput onChange={setLogin} value={login} label="Username" />
      <LoginInput
        onChange={setPassword}
        value={password}
        label="Password"
        type="password"
      />
      <LoginButton />
      {error && <ErrorMessage>{error}</ErrorMessage>}
    </LoginFormContainer>
  );
};
```

My test:

```
test("should log user in and redirect to root if login request was successful", async () => {
  // this line only mocks the response from my server
  createServer(/* loginresult */ { success: true }, /* statusCode */ 200);
  const history = createMemoryHistory();
  history.push("/login");

  const { getByLabelText, getByRole } = render(
    <BrowserRouter location={history.location} navigator={history}>
      <LoginPage />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );

  const user = userEvent.setup();

  const userNameInput = getByLabelText("Username");
  const passwordInput = getByLabelText("Password");
  const submitButton = getByRole("button");

  user.type(userNameInput, "testusername");
  user.type(passwordInput, "testpassword");
  await user.click(submitButton);

  expect(history.location.pathname).toBe("/");
});
```

Result:

```
  ● should log user in and redirect to root if login request was successful

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "/"
    Received: "/login"
```

Although the navigate is called, the test does not register any change on my history and I cannot figure out why.
Do you have any ideas what I am missing?
I tried different approaches, using HistoryRouter, Basic Router, but nothing seems to work.

Thank you in advance !

Edit:

```
  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(history.location.pathname).toBe("/");
  });
```

Does not fix my problem.

Comment: It may make a bit more sense to mock the `navigate` function and assert that it was called (*with a specific value*). This is supposed to be a ***unit test*** for the `LoginForm` afterall, not an integration test that tests the `react-router-dom` code.

Comment: Sure, that would be a solution, but - apart from the making sense fact - is there a fix for my problem? :)
Actually you are right, that would be a better way to unit test my component, but somehow it is annoying for me, that I am not able to fix that issue.

Comment: Dunno without having running code sitting in front of me. I *can* say that you'll usually want to use a `MemoryRouter`, or `HistoryRouter` and pass it a `MemoryHistory` object, as a starting point.

Comment: Tried that as well, using a MemoryRouter and only passing tha history as a prop, but the problem still exists

Comment: But nevertheless, I guess your first reply was the only proper solution for my test. It should be enough for me to test, if the mocked function is called. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

To update the history, pass the second parameter for the `navigate` function:

```
navigate('/', replace: { true });
```

See official documentation: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-navigate#usenavigate

Comment: Did not fix the issue, had the same code in a previous version, the test still assumes, that it is on "/login"

navigate("/", { replace: true });